# Error: Object of class Src\GestionConciertos\Concierto\Application\AlmacenarConcierto could not be converted to string on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've created this two classes

```
namespace Src\GestionConciertos\Concierto\Application;

final class AlmacenarConcierto{

    public function almacenar(){
        return [
            'test' => 'test text'
        ];
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace Src\GestionConciertos\Concierto\Infraestructure\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Src\GestionConciertos\Concierto\Application\AlmacenarConcierto;

final class AlmacenarConciertoController{

    private AlmacenarConcierto $almacenarConcierto;

    public function __construct(AlmacenarConcierto $almacenarConcierto)
    {
        $this->$almacenarConcierto = $almacenarConcierto;    
    }
    
    public function almacenar(Request $request){
        
       $this->almacenarConcierto->almacenar();
    }
}
```

but when a call the url that executes `AlmacenarConciertoController::almacenar` I get this error

```
Error: Object of class Src\GestionConciertos\Concierto\Application\AlmacenarConcierto could not be converted to string in file C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\src\GestionConciertos\Concierto\Infraestructure\Controllers\AlmacenarConciertoController.php on line 14
```

the problem  happens on the constructor asignation, but I dont know what is happening , I'm not trying to convert the object to a string.

```
 $this->$almacenarConcierto = $almacenarConcierto;
```

Comment: You're try to use Dependency Injection which is configured in Laravels [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container). Have you created the [bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#binding) correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you are doing `$this->$almacenarConcierto` but it should be `$this->almacenarConcierto`:

```php
public function __construct(AlmacenarConcierto $almacenarConcierto)
{
    $this->almacenarConcierto = $almacenarConcierto;    
}
```

Because you had `$this->$almacenarConcierto`, you are literally trying to convert `$almacenarConcierto` to a string so it can be used as `$this->whatever $almacenarConcierto returns as string`.